# Gearman vs ZeroMQ

Tags: php, zeromq, gearman

Has someone some feedback about distributed architectures with these engines? Which is the best, or in which cases which is the best election?

Regards!

Comment: We are thinking about a distributed architecture for our new backoffice, and we are considering this two engines to build it on top of one of this two engines. Basically to modularize the application, and make it scalable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gearman and ZeroMQ both serve different purposes. ZeroMQ is more like socket programming, or rather:

> The socket library that acts as a concurrency framework.

Gearman on the other hand is a distributed job/worker solution. Although pretty bare bones, it does serve the purpose well. Gearman has actual job servers and libraries to create clients with. With ZeroMQ you'd have to build the job server yourself as well.

So, depending on what you want the answer to which to use will differ. If you want to distribute load by dispatching jobs to several servers and clients use Gearman. If you need to do socket programming, or rather network programming with a more general purpose ZeroMQ might be what you need.